# DATE_ADD() and INTERVAL in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

please help.
I am still inserting the codeigniter function, but the error is in the data array (jtempo),
response array like this:

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'WEEK' (T_STRING)

and this is the data array.

```
$insert = array ( 'no' => $ noid, 'jtempo' => DATE_ADD (NOW (), INTERVAL +1 WEEK), );
```

how do you do it so that it doesn't error like this?
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: I get a different syntax error due to the spaces between function names and `(` when I try it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb1f45d81d37228b1fbc66759bec40d1. From the manual: "By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and the
parenthesis following it."

Comment: I have fixed it like your suggestion, but in the code I still get the same response, <p>Message:  syntax error, unexpected 'WEEK' (T_STRING)</p>

Comment: Is there any way you can dump the actual query that is being run?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put quotes for DATE_ADD() function like below, it may help you

```
$insert = array ( 'no' => $noid, 'jtempo' => 'DATE_ADD (NOW (), INTERVAL +1 WEEK)' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to give any `+` or `-` sign here in the `INTERVAL` clause.
`$insert = array('no' => $noid, 'jtempo' => 'DATE_ADD (NOW (), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)');`

Hope it helps.